How do I generate a range of numbers from a list inside ansible playbook?
In an ansible playbook, I have several lists like this:
"allowed_vlans": "1,20-22,37,39-40,600,1011-1013,1025"
What I want to do is generate a list like this from the previous list:
"allowed_vlans_range": "1, 20, 21, 22, 37, 39, 40, 600, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1025"
I can only use one file, so no external Jinja2 Templating unless it's inside the playbook file itself. I cannot use external Python plugins either.
Here's how I get my current list of allowed vlans on port-channel interfaces:
  tasks:
    - name: Get info about port channel interfaces
      cisco.nxos.nxos_facts:
        gather_subset: interfaces
        gather_network_resources: interfaces
      register: pc_info

    - name: Get info about port channel interfaces allowed vlans
      vars:
        port_channels_list: "{{ pc_info.ansible_facts.ansible_network_resources.interfaces | map(attribute='name') | flatten | to_json | from_json | regex_findall('port-channel[0-9]+') }}"
      cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
        commands:
          - show run interface {{ item }} | grep "allowed vlan"
      loop: "{{ port_channels_list }}"
      register: pc_allowed_vlans

This gets list of allowed vlans for every port-channel
    - name: Parse allowed vlans
      vars:
        allowed_vlans: "{{ item.stdout | regex_findall('[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?') }}"
        allowed_vlans_ranges: "{{ allowed_vlans | regex_findall('[0-9]+-[0-9]+') }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ allowed_vlans_ranges }}"
      loop: "{{ pc_allowed_vlans.results }}"
      register: allowed_vlans_range

This extracts the items that are formatted as "nr - nr", so "20-22", "39-40", "1011-1013" in the case of my example.
I tried using this answer's approach, but that gave me an error and it does not seem to be working in my case, where I have multiple lists of these ranges.

I've found using a Custom Filter int_span the easiest and simplest way.

PDATE: Got the previous answer's approach working - I could not figure out how to use custom plugins, since I'm using AWX. Just had to drop the Python code given into filter_plugins directory adjacent to the playbooks and then use it like any other filter.
